# Vuex store unwatch

Tags: vuex

store.watch function returns the unwatch function as documentation described.

I need to watch my state for **once**. So, can I call unwatch function inside the watch method second parameter callback function or should I do it somewhere else ?

```
var unwatch = this.$store.watch(
  state => state.foo,
  () => {
    someMethod();
    unwatch();  // Is this work ?
  }
)
```

*PS: I could not understand watcher state, with logging it to console.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, can I call unwatch function inside the watch method second parameter callback function or should I do it somewhere else ?

Answer:

> **Calling it inside the watch callback will work!**

Here is a [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/roli-unwatch-vuex-store-dm18q)

In the example I have a `count` which is stored in vuex store and a `localCount` which is stored in the component's state.

Whenever the `count` in the store changes, I call a method to update the `localCount`. Successfully, the `localCount` updated only once:

**The template:**

```
  <div id="app">
    Local Count {{ localCount }}
    <hr>
    store count {{ $store.state.count }}
    <hr>
    <button @click="increase">Increase</button>
  </div>
```

**The script:**

```
  data: () => ({
    localCount: 0
  }),

  created() {
    const unwatch = this.$store.watch(
      state => state.count,
      () => {
        this.myMethod();
        unwatch();
      }
    );
  },

  methods: {
    myMethod() {
      this.localCount++;
    },
    increase() {
      this.$store.commit("increase");
    }
  }
```

> When and where to call the `unwatch` function it depends on you needs. You can even store the unwatch function to the vue instance and when you don't want to watch anymore you can do `this.unwatch()`:

```
this.unwatch = this.$store.watch(
  state => state.foo,
  () => {
    someMethod();
  }
)
```